# Automate installation on Azure on request

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-virtual-machine

Is there a way to trigger installer inside Azure VM with an API call or hook to get the installer running? Something like a PowerShell which I can be executed remotely, I just need to pass a parameter to it which it will pass the installer.

I need something simple and quick to get going,

I have looked into `Custom Script Extension` but I don't see how can I trigger it. Not sure what is the right thing to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple options available for running commands in a VM.

While the [Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) is useful for configuration or management tasks, the **Run command** feature is very useful in that it is available even when the machine is not reachable. You can also run a [Hybrid Runbook Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker) with your custom scripts stored in an Automation account.

Refer to the following docs for more info:

- [Run scripts in your Windows VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-scripts-in-vm)
- [Run Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command)

Comment: I think the Runbook is the way to go utilising the webhook it provides. Thanks for the links I update this once I have something working

Comment: @et3rnal Have you had a chance to check this further?

Comment: Sorry not yet, I was on leave. Hopefully next week.

Comment: I tried Run command to get it to trigger a PowerShell within the VM and it works fine. I tested that with endpoint as well I guess I have what I need now just need to put them together and get that request securely to trigger the script. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Invoke-AzVmRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-4.7.0) to do this. The script needs to be local to where the cmdlet is being run.

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'rgname' -VMName 'vmname' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'sample.ps1' -Parameter @{param1 = "var1"; param2 = "var2"}
```

Comment: And how would I automate the trigger of this?